# prestashop webservice : using PHP to make a CRUD application, issue retrieving informations on an XML

Tags: php, xml, web-services, crud, prestashop

good day, i'm starting a CRUD application on prestashop, i would like to use the webservice to update, create or delete the products, users and orders via a php application started by the program that manage the storage.

i've look at the prestashop guide:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

and now i'm trying to get the things done.

i'm actually recieving an xml which represent the structure of a product:

```
<?php
// Here we define constants /!\ You need to replace this parameters
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://www.server.com/prestashop/');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'blahblahbla');
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');




    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
    $opt['id'] =1;

        $xml = $webService->get($opt);
        $resources = $xml->children()->children();



foreach ($resources as $nodeKey => $node)
    {

        echo $nodeKey . " : ". $resources->$nodeKey ."<br>";
    }


/*$opt = array('resource' => 'products');
$opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$opt['id'] = 1;
$xml = $webService->edit($opt);*/


?>
```

the first problem i got:

the field "name" has some childs in the xml, which are the different lenguages so, in the loop where i navigate throught the nodes, i would like to "go into" those that have a child... because actually the name i try to "`echo`" is empty, but if i see the xml, i can see 2 nodes under `<name>` which contains the names in 2 different lenguages.
thats all for now, i'll post more and more questions later :D

thanks in advance!

Comment: http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-3393?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel
i founded here some usefull informations about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing a SimpleXMLElement that has children (http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).  In this case it has children named languages.

```
Array
(
    [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [language] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Therefore you would access like below.

```
if($resources->$nodeKey->children()){

    $children = false;
    foreach($resources->$nodeKey->children() as $child){
        $children[] = $child;
    }

    echo $nodeKey . " : [" . @implode(", ", $children) . "]<br>";
}
else    
    echo $nodeKey . " : ". $resources->$nodeKey ."<br>";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [language] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
name : [iPod Nano]
```